# Сочетание «с точки зрения» — факультативное обособление?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, недопустимая-метка, с-точки-зрения

По [«Розенталю», пункт 9-16,](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122) оборот с точки зрения, если имеет значение по мнению. А может, обособление таких обстоятельств (обстоятельств! То есть всех случаем, где оборот не имеет значение ’по мнению’) факультативное? Может, их также можно обособлять, если подчëркиваешь их смысл или для пояснения? Давайте разберëмся.

Вот несколько примеров:

`С точки зрения маркетинга(,) этот продукт имеет большой потенциал для успеха на рынке`;

`С точки зрения логики(,) его аргументы были слабыми и не смогли убедить меня`;

Можно ли обособить обороты выше?

`С моей точки зрения, изучение космоса - это возможность узнать больше о нашей вселенной и ее красоте`.

А в послкднем, как я понимаю, запяьые «зафиксированы».

Как считаете вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обособление** во всех случаях:

1. **Обстоятельственный оборот** со значением условия, его можно заменить придаточным условным (= *если рассматривать с точки зрения*). Пауза **грамматическая**, четко обозначенная:

***С точки зрения маркЕтинга**, // этот продукт имеет большой потенциал для успеха на рынке.*

***С точки зрения лОгики**, // его аргументы были слабыми и не смогли убедить меня.*

2. **Вводное сочетание**, обозначение мнения автора (как он думает). **Пауза** небольшая, основная граница сообщения перед тире:

***С моей точки зрения,** / изучение кОсмоса — // это возможность узнать больше о нашей вселенной и ее красоте.*

Comment: То есть если нет значения ’по мнению’, факультативно обособляем?

Comment: А как иначе? Правила не позволяют? Но это ж не мнение АВТОРА, а рассмотрение вопроса с различных точек зрения.  Обязательности нет. Обособленную конструкцию можно посчитать вводной, но по другой тематике:  способ построения текста, оформление мыслей и т.д. Но это не источник сообщения.  В необособленном варианте оборот будет членом предложения (обстоятельством).